# How to reference web service with my asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have my own web service application with more then one .asmx file.
Now i am not getting how can i reference web service with my web application as "Add Web Reference".

I want to connect with both asmx files at once.
Means once i connect web service as add web reference and i can call both .asmx file from my code behind page.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? If you are using .NET 3.5 or 4.0, then  you should use "Add Service Reference" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't work that way.  You have to reference each web service or consolidate them.

You could do this:

[Invoking Web Service dynamically using HttpWebRequest](http://geekswithblogs.net/marcel/archive/2007/03/26/109886.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When you add a web reference to your application, Visual Studio creates a proxy class that you use to connect to the web service. You will not connect to the web service directly. The proxy class name is set when you add the reference. It suggests a name for you that you can change.

As long as you are using the proxy classes that are generated, you should be able to connect to as many web services as you desire.

I hope that helps.